# MSTest - DeploymentItem attribute unavailable on windows store test project

Tags: c#, mstest, windows-store-apps, deploymentitem

As the title says - I can't find a way of including a file with a windows store test project. (A standard .NET test project works fine)

Right click on the solution and execute : Add new project -> C# -> Windows Store -> Unit test library (Windows store apps)

You get this boilerplate, to which I have added the DeploymentItem attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTestLibrary1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        // this does not compile; DeploymentItem attribute not found
        [DeploymentItem("wibble.txt")]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So what am I missing? Is it simply not possible to include data in windows store unit tests, or do I need a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have been deploying data files is by using a post-build copy.  I have my data in my project under a directory called "TestData", which gets copied to the output after a build.

The following lines are set in the "Build Events" tab of the my test project's properties:

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)AppX" mkdir "$(TargetDir)AppX"
if not exist "$(TargetDir)AppX\TestData" mkdir "$(TargetDir)AppX\TestData"
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)TestData\*.*" "$(TargetDir)AppX\TestData\"
```

A couple of notes:

- my unit tests refer to the data files under the directory `TestData`, and not `AppX\TestData`.
- the post-build action above will only copy files that have been set in your project as 1) a content file and 2) as being copied to output.

Answer (score 0):

[DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is contained at `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace in which you are not having a reference.

You have to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll`.

Comment: A windows store test project runs under WinRT and it's heavily sandboxed so you can't just add references to standard .NET DLLs. I did try browsing directly to the UnitTestFramework dll to add it but it still doesn't want to recognise that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use @chue-x Build Events, then [TestInitialize] something like:

```
        var site = "TestData";
        var appx = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        var reposTestFolder = await appx.GetFolderAsync(site);
        var testFiles = await reposTestFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        var localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var reposFolder = await localfolder.CreateFolderAsync(site, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        foreach (var file in testFiles)
        {
            await file.CopyAsync(reposFolder);
        }
```

Now the TestData is available to the app under test.